# looking for a key in a dictionary using Counter() for anagram

Tags: python, anagram

I am trying to look for keys with similar letters (anagram) in an imaginary dictionay and I have this incomplete code:

```
from collections import Counter
diction = {'crazy':'dd', 'abd':'ddd','cat':'bad'}
word = input('what is the word?')
new=[]
for i in dic:
    if(Counter(word) == Counter(....):
        new.append(...)
    else:
        continue
 
print(f'{word} and {new} are anagrams')
```

I have no idea how to check for the keys and if they match the given input. Appreciate your help

Comment: How do you define "similar"?  To check for an anagram, if the words are the same length, sort the letters and check for equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think `Counter` is a good solution here, probably better than sorting because it is O(n). For example, `Counter("arc") == Counter("car")` returns `True`. So you were on the right track.

There are typos in your code (`dic` should be `diction`). Your for loop was already iterating through keys, so you were close:

```
from collections import Counter
diction = {'crazy':'dd', 'abd':'ddd','cat':'bad'}
word = input('what is the word?')
new=[]
for i in diction:
    if(Counter(word) == Counter(i)):
        new.append(i)
    else:
        continue
 
print(f'{word} and {new} are anagrams')
```

If I input "tac", it will print:

> tac and ['cat'] are anagrams